# How to get the terminal type with empty env

Tags: c, env, termcap

I'ld like to know if there any way to get the type of the terminal but get env("TERM").

```
tgetent(NULL, getenv("TERM"));
```

But if i execute my program with an empty env

```
env -i ./a.out
```

i wont be able to get the terminal type i need to use the termcap library.

Is there any way to find the terminal type with an empty env ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not *find* the terminal environment, but rather, *set* it so that your applications will work properly.  It should be set to correspond with the capabilities of the terminal your program runs in.

There are some special cases, such as `cron`, where you do not have a terminal, but for some reason want to be able to use termcap (more likely, a termcap interface to a terminfo library, by the way).  In ncurses, there are a few entries such as `generic`, `unknown` and `dumb` which refer to terminals that cannot be used for full-screen mode.

Most (say 2/3 or more) of the terminal emulators in use today have a reasonable level of compatibility with DEC VT100's, so setting `TERM` to `vt100` "works".  For a better fit, you need to know what the terminal does.  Some people will for instance say to set it to `xterm`, but that may not be good advice (ncurses FAQ *[Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic)*).